# Top N columns in a data frame with their corresponding column names and row names

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame which depicts similarity between users by a numeric number. A representative dataset is as mentioned below:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9 C10
R1  72  71  9   47  77  58  74  52  19  82
R2  43  25  75  100 66  97  71  76  26  57
R3  1   32  87  81  88  66  84  29  15  49
R4  66  68  22  63  40  53  32  69  57  58
R5  42  34  30  77  36  41  61  68  61  35
R6  59  23  38  3   20  86  72  81  58  1
R7  40  86  45  21  44  63  79  77  35  47
R8  15  75  15  19  34  72  96  28  24  38
R9  13  69  2   30  81  72  38  95  92  10
R10 69  26  23  100 55  10  29  16  20  38
```

I want the **top N** (for eg 7) columns of each row along with the column name and the corresponding row name. So it can be another `dataframe` as mentioned below. Either it can be in a single step or multiple steps with intermediaries data frames formed to arrive at this solution.

```
col1 col2 col3
R1  C10 82
R1  C5  77
R1  C7  74
R1  C1  72
R1  C2  71
R1  C6  58
R1  C8  52
R2  C4  100
R2  C6  97
R2  C8  76
R2  C3  75
R2  C7  71
R2  C5  66
R2  C10 57
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, what have you tried so far ? You might consider reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution using the `dplyr` package. You can turn your columns to rows for each entry of your first variable by using the `melt` function. Then you simply group by your first variable and arrange your values for each group. In the end you can slice any number of points you want. In my example I got the top 7:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  melt(id.vars = first(names(.)),
       measure.vars = names(.)[names(.) != first(names(.))]) %>%
  group_by(!!as.name(first(names(.)))) %>%
  top_n(7)
```

I built it so that the names of your dataframe can vary. You can simply adjust it if your dataframes are all named the same way by exchanging `first(names(.))` for `C1`(or any name you like).

Comment: You can use `top_n` instead of the `arrange` and `slice` pairing for some more concise code.

Comment: you can also use `gather` like `library(tidyverse);
d %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(k, v, -rowname) %>% 
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  top_n(7) `

Answer (score 0):

This uses no packages.  If you want a data.table result replace `data.frame` with `data.table`.

```
N <- 3
data.frame(row = rownames(DF), 
  value = t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) rev(tail(sort(x), N)))), 
  col = t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) rev(names(DF)[tail(order(x), N)]))))
```

giving:

```
    row value.1 value.2 value.3 col.1 col.2 col.3
R1   R1      82      77      74   C10    C5    C7
R2   R2     100      97      76    C4    C6    C8
R3   R3      88      87      84    C5    C3    C7
R4   R4      69      68      66    C8    C2    C1
R5   R5      77      68      61    C4    C8    C9
R6   R6      86      81      72    C6    C8    C7
R7   R7      86      79      77    C2    C7    C8
R8   R8      96      75      72    C7    C2    C6
R9   R9      95      92      81    C8    C9    C5
R10 R10     100      69      55    C4    C1    C5
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "C1 C2 C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9 C10
R1 72 71 9 47 77 58 74 52 19 82
R2 43 25 75 100 66 97 71 76 26 57
R3 1 32 87 81 88 66 84 29 15 49
R4 66 68 22 63 40 53 32 69 57 58
R5 42 34 30 77 36 41 61 68 61 35
R6 59 23 38 3 20 86 72 81 58 1
R7 40 86 45 21 44 63 79 77 35 47
R8 15 75 15 19 34 72 96 28 24 38
R9 13 69 2 30 81 72 38 95 92 10
R10 69 26 23 100 55 10 29 16 20 38"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with base `R`:

```
D <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9 C10
R1  72  71  9   47  77  58  74  52  19  82
R2  43  25  75  100 66  97  71  76  26  57
R3  1   32  87  81  88  66  84  29  15  49
R4  66  68  22  63  40  53  32  69  57  58
R5  42  34  30  77  36  41  61  68  61  35
R6  59  23  38  3   20  86  72  81  58  1
R7  40  86  45  21  44  63  79  77  35  47
R8  15  75  15  19  34  72  96  28  24  38
R9  13  69  2   30  81  72  38  95  92  10
R10 69  26  23  100 55  10  29  16  20  38")
top7 <- function(x) { y <- x[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:7]] ; data.frame(Col=names(y), value=y) 
}
L <- apply(D[,], 1, top7)
result <- L[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(L)) result <- rbind(result, L[[i]])
data.frame(Row=rep(rownames(D), each=7), result, row.names = NULL)
```

gives:

```
> data.frame(Row=rep(rownames(D), each=7), result, row.names = NULL)
   Row Col value
1   R1 C10    82
2   R1  C5    77
3   R1  C7    74
4   R1  C1    72
5   R1  C2    71
6   R1  C6    58
7   R1  C8    52
8   R2  C4   100
9   R2  C6    97
10  R2  C8    76
11  R2  C3    75
12  R2  C7    71
13  R2  C5    66
14  R2 C10    57
15  R3  C5    88
16  R3  C3    87
17  R3  C7    84
18  R3  C4    81
19  R3  C6    66
20  R3 C10    49
21  R3  C2    32
22  R4  C8    69
23  R4  C2    68
24  R4  C1    66
25  R4  C4    63
26  R4 C10    58
27  R4  C9    57
28  R4  C6    53
29  R5  C4    77
30  R5  C8    68
31  R5  C7    61
32  R5  C9    61
33  R5  C1    42
34  R5  C6    41
35  R5  C5    36
36  R6  C6    86
37  R6  C8    81
38  R6  C7    72
39  R6  C1    59
40  R6  C9    58
41  R6  C3    38
42  R6  C2    23
43  R7  C2    86
44  R7  C7    79
45  R7  C8    77
46  R7  C6    63
47  R7 C10    47
48  R7  C3    45
49  R7  C5    44
50  R8  C7    96
51  R8  C2    75
52  R8  C6    72
53  R8 C10    38
54  R8  C5    34
55  R8  C8    28
56  R8  C9    24
57  R9  C8    95
58  R9  C9    92
59  R9  C5    81
60  R9  C6    72
61  R9  C2    69
62  R9  C7    38
63  R9  C4    30
64 R10  C4   100
65 R10  C1    69
66 R10  C5    55
67 R10 C10    38
68 R10  C7    29
69 R10  C2    26
70 R10  C3    23
```

or (with ranks)

```
data.frame(Row=rep(rownames(D), each=7), Rank=1:7, result, row.names = NULL)
```

Comment: Lots of interesting solutions and clean solutions!! Thanks guys for chipping in. Its been of a great help.

Comment: The for loop here is taking a lot of time for a large dataset.

for (i in 2:length(L)) result <- rbind(result, L[[i]]).

Is there any other way to avoid the loop in this step for a faster processing.